# Obtener parametros de url

Tags: php, javascript, html

Como hago para obtener y almacenar en una variable los parametros de una url como ésta:

> /mapa.php#13/10.3761/-75.4867

Donde vemos que siguen unos valores a partir del "#".
Como pueden ver no hay variables GET, ¿como sería?

Answer (score 2):

En `PHP` se puede utilizar la función `explode()`.  Esta función lo que hace es recibir un string o en este caso la url.  El primer parámetro que recibe es el que se va a buscar para separa y el segundo la cadena a la cual se va a evaluar.

```
$url = "/mapa.php#13/10.3761/-75.4867";
$explode = explode("/", $url);
```

Para mostrar los resultados se llama la variable es donde se retorna el resultado de la función y con una posición.  Para recorrer `explode()` se inicia desde la posición 0. En este caso no va a mostrar nada porque no hay nada antes del primer /

```
echo $var01 = $explode[1];
echo "<br>";
echo $var02 = $explode[2];
echo "<br>";
echo $var01 = $explode[3];
echo "<br>";
```

En el caso de separar el numeral se utiliza la misma función

```
$exnum = explode("#",$var01);

echo $exnum[0];
echo "<br>";
echo $exnum[1];
```

Esto es lo que se mostraría como resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Lo que colocas en la dirección iniciando con # se llama hash.

Puedes obtenerlo utilizando javascript con *window.location.hash*.

Teniendo la cadena ya puedes hacerle split y obtener los valores.

```js
var hash = window.location.hash;

var valores = hash.substr(1).split('/');
```

Ojalá te sirva.

Saludos.